# swift: Show seconds in label.

Tags: ios, swift

I have this array of seconds:

```
var modeLight = [5,30,60,30,60,30]
```

And I have timer:

```
@IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
var seconds = 60
var timer = Timer()
var isTimerRunning = false
var resumeTapped = false

@IBAction func startAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if isTimerRunning == false {
                    runTimer()
                }
}

func runTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(MasterViewController.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        isTimerRunning = true
    }

    @objc func updateTimer() {
        if seconds < 1 {
            timer.invalidate()
            //Send alert to indicate "time's up!"
        } else {
            seconds -= 1
            timerLabel.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(seconds))
        }
    }

    func timeString(time:TimeInterval) -> String {
        let hours = Int(time) / 3600
        let minutes = Int(time) / 60 % 60
        let seconds = Int(time) % 60
        return String(format:"%02i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)
    }
```

I want to take seconds value from `modeLight` and show it in `timerLabel`. After first element (for example `5`) will expire I want to show next and etc. How to do it?

Comment: you need to running timer and value of timer is equal to the value of then you can use it.

it's right ? that is i am understanding from your question.

Comment: why did you try to init `timer` twice? when did you [`fire()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1414035-fire) your _second_ timer?

Comment: @holex I need to init `timer ` once. What do you mean?

Comment: @user, oh, I dod not know you don't know what you are doing... so, why do you need the line `var timer = Timer()` in your view? (hint: initing the timer _before_ creating your _second_ timer).

Comment: @holex I should change it on this `var timer: Timer!`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of the array index to use.

Add an index property and initialise it

```
var modeLight = [5,30,60,30,60,30]
var timerIndex: Int 
var timer: Timer!
```

Use index in your `updateTimer()` func

```
func runTimer() {
    timerIndex = 0
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(MasterViewController.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func updateTimer() {
    if seconds < 1 {
        timerIndex += 1
        if timerIndex >= modeLight.count { // to be safe
            endTimer()
            return
        }
        seconds = modeLight[timerIndex]
    } else {
        seconds -= 1
    }

    timerLabel.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(seconds))
}

private func endTimer() {
    timer.invalidate()
    timerLabel.text = "00:00:00"
}
```

Comment: Good start, although at the moment he has a "seconds" variable which is no longer being interpreted.  Pretty sure the intent was for 60 or 30 to be the number of seconds for the timer to run before switching to a different mode

Comment: Yeah, directly after posting this I realised I might have misunderstood the question. Re-reading it now...

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Cannot subscript a value of type '[Int]' with an index of type 'Timer'

Comment: Not to hard to figure out, is it? I'll update the code

Comment: @user, new version. Also changed `runTimer()` slightly

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It does not work exactly as I wanted it. I need get first value from `modeLight `. It is 5. After that in my label I want to show 5, 4, 3, 2, 1. After that I want to get next value from `modeLight `. It is 30. And I want to show in label 30, 29, 28, and etc.